# Как сделать рекурсивный запрос выборки из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql, oracle, symfony, plsql

Как работают `START WITH`, `CONNECT BY PRIOR`?

Помогите сформировать рекурсивный иерархический запрос с данными:

```
Ленинградская обл->всеволожский р-н->сертолово
```

Моя попытка:

```
SELECT reg.code
FROM   all_region reg
WHERE  reg.code in (
         SELECT d.region_id 
         FROM   for_notify d 
         WHERE  d.email IS NOT NULL 
         AND d.partner_id = 777)
and    ROWNUM = 1
START  WITH reg.code = '48'
CONNECT BY PRIOR  reg.parent_code = reg.code
```

Знаю как рекурсивно работала бы функция с запросами и реализовал на php поиск.

1. Стартует функция с заказом где есть все необходимые данные, и пустым `find_parent`.
2. Если находим в текущем заказе `region_id` который бы удовлетворял условиям:

   ```
   WHERE dic.region_id = :region
   AND   dic.partner_id = :partner
   AND   dic.email IS NOT NULL
   ```

   то заканчиваем поиск.
3. Если не нашли, то фиксируем код региона в `$currentregion`, вызоваем нашу функцию с дочерним регионом, ищем его родителя и возвращаемся к шагу 2.

Код:

```
private function foo($order,$find_parent)
   {
       if($find_parent==null) {
//            ищем в текущем регионе
           $currentregion = $order->getCodeRegion();
       }else{
//            прнинимаем текущий регион и ищем его родителя
           $query=$this->em->createQuery("
               SELECT 
                 r.parent_code 
               FROM 
                 MainBundle:Allregion r  
               WHERE dic.region_id = :region
               ")->setParameters(array('region'=>$find_parent));
           $currentregion=$query->getResult();
       }

       $query = $this->em->createQuery("
           SELECT
               dic
           FROM
               MainBundle:fornotify dic
           WHERE dic.region_id = :region
           AND dic.partner_id = :partner
           AND dic.email IS NOT NULL
       ")->setParameters(array('partner' => $order->getPartnerId(), 'region' => $currentregion));

       if($query->getResult()==null){
           //если не нашел кого оповестить передаем ребенка и ищем родителя
           $this->foo($order,$currentregion);
       }
       else {
           return $query->getResult();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Опишите саму задачу. Какие у вас есть таблицы, что должен получить запрос на выходе. У вас только куски кода без описания того, что они должны найти.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @pegoopik  непонятно что хотите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если последний уровень заранее известен, например, как в вопросе равен 3:

```
with region as (
    select  00 reg_id, 00 preg_id, ' ' regname         from dual where 1=0 union all
    select  11, null, 'Ленинградская обл' from dual union all
    select  21, 11,   'всеволожский р-н'  from dual union all
    select  31, 21,   'сертолово'         from dual
)
select substr(sys_connect_by_path(regname, '->'),3) regpath 
from   region
where  level = 3
connect by prior reg_id = preg_id 
start   with preg_id is null;
```

> Ленинградская обл->всеволожский р-н->сертолово

Если последний уровень не известен заранее, то можно по условию - только для путей с листовыми узлами в иерархии:

```
with region as (
    select  00 reg_id, 00 preg_id, ' ' regname from dual where 1=0 union all
    select  11, null,  'Ленинградская обл' from dual union all
    select  21, 11,    'всеволожский р-н'  from dual union all
    select  31, 21,    'сертолово'         from dual union all
    select  12, null,  'Центральный ф.о.'  from dual union all
    select  22, 12,    'Брянская обл.'     from dual union all
    select  32, 22,    'Маньковский р-н'   from dual union all
    select  42, 32,    'Чертилково'        from dual
), 
regpath as (
  select level, 
         connect_by_isleaf isleaf, 
         sys_connect_by_path(regname, '->') path, 
         '->' path_prefix 
  from   region r
  connect by prior reg_id = preg_id 
  start  with preg_id is null
)
select regexp_replace(path, '^' || path_prefix) place 
from   regpath
where  isleaf = 1;
```

> Ленинградская обл->всеволожский р-н->сертолово
>   Центральный ф.о.->Брянская обл.->Маньковский р-н->Чертилково

Подробнее об иерархических запросах в [оф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332).

Comment: Спасибо , но бывает и 4)

Comment: т.е. задача показать только последние листки в иерархии - в нашем примере это населённые пункты. Если нет - уберите where.